org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host in docker
I created a connection from a spring boot app to docker, but I got an error
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host

I used the solution from org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host and I attached the ssl query parameters, but it didn't work in docker-compose.yml:
services:
  belt-microservice:
    build: belt-microservices
    container_name: belt-microservice
    restart: always
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db-belt:5432/belt_microservices?ssl=true&sslmode=require
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db-belt
  db-belt:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db-belt
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=belt_microservices
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    ports:
      - "5000:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
volumes:
  pgdata:

It ended up in
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server does not support SSL.

I tried to add a network to the docker-compose.yml
networks:
  default:
    external: false

but it only resulted in another error
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.

How to make the postgres container support SSL or avoid the error about the entry for host?

I solved it adding a custom name to the folders for PGDATA in the db services' configurations, as in this answer.
The final docker-compose.yml reads
services:
  belt-microservice:
    build: belt-microservices
    container_name: belt-microservice
    restart: always
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db-belt:5432/belt_microservices
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db-belt
  crossbelt-microservice:
    build: crossbelt-microservices
    container_name: crossbelt-microservice
    restart: always
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db-crossbelt:5432/crossbelt_microservices
      - BELT_URL=http://belt-microservice:8080
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    depends_on:
      - db-crossbelt
      - belt-microservice
  report-microservice:
    build: report-microservices
    container_name: report-microservice
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
  db-belt:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db-belt
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=belt_microservices
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/belt/
    ports:
      - "5000:5432"
    restart: always
  db-crossbelt:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db-crossbelt
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=crossbelt_microservices
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/crossbelt/
    ports:
      - "5001:5432"

I don't know if I had to add POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust, it's not recommended.
